# How to disable TLSv1 in Apache

Tags: apache2, ssl, tls

I have installed Apache on an Ubuntu server, and have SSL installed through "Let's Encrypt".

The SSL certificate is valid, but when running the URL of the website thought https://whynopadlock.com, it gives the following reason why Chrome does not grant a padlock:
`You currently have TLSv1 enabled.`

Within the file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf`, I have changed the line for `SSLProtocol` to the following:
`SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3`

Why is this change not allowing Chrome to provide the padlock? Is it because I am using virtual hosts? What is the correct configuration to disable TLSv1 in Apache on Ubunutu?

Answer (score 2):

What i have on my apache config is

```
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
```

Get a rating for your config on:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

Comment: I believe I tried this as well (from the Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator). I have restarted Apache but still no padlock. Am I updating the wrong file? Is the configuration cached somewhere?

Comment: Try it as i put it. I don't think it's being cached. Try `find /etc/apache2/ | xargs grep SSLProtocol -sn` to see how many of those configurations do you have.

Comment: There are two, but that is okay? Because they are both the same configuration within ssl.conf. One is in the `mods-enabled` directory, and one is in the `mods-available` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this issue as well.. I could not get away from the B rating of SSLlabs. I found that, using a selfsigned certificate from LetsEncrypt, the LE installation has a separate config file that also has the TLS settings. This file is on /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf. I changed the TLS level settings there, restarted apache and getting A-level now.